# Laravel - Finding progress method locations for CLI app

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm attempting to write a CLI app to help do some tasks quickly. I'm using Laravel 5.1.

I want to implement the [progress bar](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#command-io) but I'm using windows (cmd.exe) and it's coming up with weird characters instead of the progress bar.

I have read the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html) and it states you can configure the progress bar, but Laravel only seems to give you some helper methods, such as `progressAdvance`, `progressFinish` etc.

**My question is** I cannot find where these methods are stored!! I have tried searching the [Laravel API documentation](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/) with no success, and all I can find in the type hinting is contract interfaces! that the `Illuminate\Console\Command` class extends.

I've come across this problem before. All I want to do is find a single method, and it seems insanely difficult unless you know the framework inside out.

**tl/dr**

How do I find out what file a given method is stored in. For example, using Laravel commands (progress bar), how do I find out what file the `progressAdvance` method is stored in.

Comment: When I am looking for a function name I always use the find in folder functionality (in sublimetext)

Comment: Good idea, (I'm using Sublime), I'll try that, but I would have thought there should be an easier way other than to scan a few thousand php files!

Comment: I gave you file locations in my answer..did you find the files....?

Comment: @hhsadiq Thanks for the answer, I'll mark it as accepted, as it was what I was looking for this time, but I was asking about more general methods (not limited to the `progressAdvance()` methods). Thanks for the locations though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the `progressAdvance()` in following places two places.

```
 '/vendor/symfony/console/Style/SymfonyStyle.php'    //line no: 275

 '/vendor/symfony/console/Style/StyleInterface.php'  //line no: 153
```